# What's the best way to water an orchid that grows on coconut husk?

Tags: watering, containers, plant-care, orchids

[image: self watering pot for orchid]

I have and it grows on coconut husk. I tried to water it, but seemed like the coconut husk didn't keep the water too long to make the orchid stays humid. So I came up with and idea to make self watering pot where the coconut husk is slightly dipped into the water in a jar. It has new young stem after a week I treat it that way. I put the fertilizer into the water too sometimes.

Just wondering if this self watered pot idea effective enough?

Answer (score 4):

What a fabulous idea!
Another way that I have found effective is to fill a hand spray with water and trace elements and spray it on the orchid.
I use ENO or Epsom salts in the spray and have had good results.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I definitely will try your technique! One thing that I'd probably need to learn from next step, if either spraying it to the orchid's leaf will give better result than spray it to the orchid's root. 
I heard some people use water from rice washing to get B1 vitamin and mix it with MSG to spray to get the orchid's root healthier.